# Hide ActiveAdmin menu but does not disable it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

In my AA app, I use the following instruction to hide the menu I do not want non admin users to see:

```
menu :if => proc{ current_user.is_admin? }
```

but this does not prevent those users to enter /admin/users in the url and to access the users menu content. What is the best way to prevent non admin user to access hidden menu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with cancan or can write your own filter like this,

```
controller do
  before_filter :check_admin
  def check_admin
    unless current_user.is_admin?
     redirect_to "/", :error => "Access denied"
    end
  end
end
```

for cancan gem, you need to define ability file and then you can use

```
 controller.authorize_resource
```

method provided by activeadmin.

Comment: Thanks, the first solution is working fine. I've heard a lot of Cancan, I'll definitively give it a try then.